# Dante server closed for connection

Tags: proxy, vps, socks-proxy, socks5, amazon-vpc

I'm setting up a socks5 server using amazon aws. On my vps I've ubuntu 18.04 I've installed dante-server via `sudo apt-get install`. After that I edited the dante config file and enabled danted.service. It seems to work correctly but I can't connect to it. To check the connection I use:

```
curl --socks5 proxyuser:proxypass@myvpsip:1080 ident.me; echo
```

This is danted.conf:

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log

internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0

socksmethod: username

user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}

client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}

socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}

socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

sudo systemctl status danted.service returns me that:

```
danted.service - SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/danted.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-06-07 13:26:44 UTC; 27min ago
     Docs: man:danted(8)
           man:danted.conf(5)
  Process: 19901 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/danted -D (code=exited, 

status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19887 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c        uid=`sed -n -e "s/[[:space:]]//g" -e "s/#.*//" -e "/^user\.privileged/{s/[^:]*://p;q;}" /etc/danted.conf`;      if [ -n "$uid"
 Main PID: 19902 (danted)
    Tasks: 20 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: ...

Jun 07 13:26:44 ip-172-31-10-116 systemd[1]: Stopped SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
Jun 07 13:26:44 ip-172-31-10-116 systemd[1]: Starting SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Jun 07 13:26:44 ip-172-31-10-116 systemd[1]: Started SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
```

Answer (score 0):

After two days searching for solution I found that I must open needed port to connect. That I successfully done via bar in the amazon site.